# Clojure - outputs appearing in wrong order

Tags: clojure, shortest-path

I am working on a route planning robot. The robot traverses rooms in an office using ubergraph and can collect and deliver parcels. However when I am wanting to plan a route and then output the fact a parcel has been delivered the "Delivered" message is outputting before the route plan.

I know why this is occurring and it's because of the order in my if statements etc. However, I have tried every location I can think of for the prints to go and I can't get it working.

Can anyone see where I need to move the following line of code to?

```
(journey start end)
```

Below if the full code for the function it is contained within.

```
(defn multipleparcels [parcel]
  (def newparcel (first parcel))
  (def start (:start newparcel))
  (def end (:end newparcel))
  (def delivery (:delivery newparcel))
  (if (empty? parcel)
    (println "Deliveries Completed")
    (if (= delivery "Delivery")
      (println "Parcel Delivered")
      (println "Parcel Collected")))  
  (journey start end)
  (multipleparcels (rest parcel)))
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Edit: What I have managed to now implement

```
(defn multipleparcels [parcel]
  (let [newparcel (first parcel)
   start (:start newparcel)
   end (:end newparcel)
   delivery (:delivery newparcel)]
  (if (empty? parcel)
    (println "Deliveries Completed")
    (doall (journey start end)
    (if delivery
      (println "Parcel Delivered")
      (println "Parcel Collected")) 
  (multipleparcels (rest parcel))))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you did serious mistakes with this code(wrote all imperative) before jumping into Clojure code, check some Clojure tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`journey` is apparently some side-effecting function, but it doesn't really do anything here, since you ignore the value, and since `start`, `end`, and `delivery` are being derived from the function's parameter.

A few things to consider:

1. You should not be `def`ing inside of this function.
2. You are checking whether `(= delivery "Delivery")` ... this is a binary condition, so it's probably best to let `delivery` be a simple boolean, so it's `(if delivery then else)`
3. Again, I'm not sure about `journey`, but it's not doing anything here.
4. Your function will loop forever, since the last line, `multipleparcels`, is executed every time.
5. Destructuring is not necessary, but can clean things up a bit
6. Your function is not named well, as `multipleparcels` does not really say anything about what the function is *doing*.  Also, your parameter `parcel` implies that it receives one parcel, when the context suggests that it should be receiving several.

Here is code that does something, even if it's not what you want, and maybe you can get some ideas about how to process your data:

```
(def data
  [{:start "a" :end "c" :delivery true}
   {:start "d" :end "f" :delivery false}
   {:start "x" :end "y" :delivery true}])

(defn process-parcels
  [[{:keys [start end delivery] :as parcel} & parcels]]
  (if parcel
    (do
      (if delivery
        (println "Parcel Delivered")
        (println "Parcel Collected"))
      (process-parcels parcels))
    (println "Deliveries Completed")))

(process-parcels data)

Parcel Delivered
Parcel Collected
Parcel Delivered
Deliveries Completed
=> nil
```

I suggest taking a step back, and doing some basic clojure exercises so you can understand the difference between assigning a value to a variable, which is what you're doing and common in an imperative style of programming, and evaluating expressions.  Once you get the hang of this, it becomes much easier and is fun!  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I have added the code relating to journey and showed how I am using the functions to my question. I will try implement your style of code now. Any further tips relating to my other code much appreciated

Comment: Hi Josh, I have implemented some of your suggestions, I now have it working. Is the code I have written more functional or is there still issues with it?

Comment: @benjano you have some misplaced parens -- the call to `doall` is not correct (and even if you do intend to force realization of a lazy seq, which is what I'm assuming you're doing there, you're not doing anything with the result; even if it has side-effects that are necessary to your program, your function only depends on its single input, `parcel`, so your `journey` call cannot be doing anything relevant to this function).  Also, your indentation and style makes it unclear.  However, it is better than your first attempt.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean about me calling journey? Journey is my function that plans the shortest path and prints out the route taken. I'm unsure what you mean about it not being relevant

Comment: @benjano If my answer helped you and you have moved on with other questions, etc., please mark the answer as accepted and upvote, if you feel that it was helpful.